# Ionic build android failed with 403 Http respose from Gradle, JAVA_HOME not valid

Tags: windows, cordova, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, ionic-framework

I am using Windows 7X64 machine and trying to build Andriod application using `cordova/ionic CLI v1.5.5`. I am getting this error that I couldn't solve.

```
"You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project"
```

with commands `ionic build android` and `cordova build android`. The command `ionic platform add android` was successful. I am working with  Android sdk (API 22) using the Android SDK Manager. I also made sure that PATH variable is correctly set.

Full transcript of process is:

```
C:\Users\ddevkota\Desktop\freshIonic>ionic build android
Running command: "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" C:\Users\ddevkota\Desktop\fr
eshIonic\hooks\after_prepare\010_add_platform_class.js C:\Users\ddevkota\Desktop
\freshIonic
add to body class: platform-android
Running command: cmd "/s /c "C:\Users\ddevkota\Desktop\freshIonic\platforms\andr
oid\cordova\build.bat""
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\ddevkota\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.7.0_15
Running: C:\Users\ddevkota\Desktop\freshIonic\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuild
Debug -b C:\Users\ddevkota\Desktop\freshIonic\platforms\android\build.gradle -Do
rg.gradle.daemon=true
Downloading http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Serv
er returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://services.gradle.org/distribu
tions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip
        at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAcc
essManager.java:78)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:47)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL:
 http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLCon
nection.java:1625)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:59)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:45)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:60)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:47)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAcc
essManager.java:65)
        ... 3 more

C:\Users\ddevkota\Desktop\freshIonic\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.
js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s /c "C:\Users\ddevkota\Desktop\freshI
onic\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b C:\Users\ddevkota\Desktop\freshI
onic\platforms\android\build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true"
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1

You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\ddevkota\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:134:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)
```

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**NOTE: This turns out to be a permission issue in client (403). I connected my machine to different network and it started working. All build process. If you wanna do it manually here is how far I got.**

**Solution for not Valid JAVA_HOME**

After spending days and uninstalling all versions of java, reinstalling only one version and setting up Environment Variable`JAVA_HOME` as `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_15` I solved the problem.

However there was another issue of ionic build android error when downloading gradle.

This was solved as I added gradle to my project offline.

**Solution for not Gradle 403 Http response**

Do the following:
After downloading gradle from issued link (here is https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip) paste it in somewhere likes `myApp\platforms\android\gradle\gradle-2.2.1-all.zip` and in build.js from `myApp\platforms\android\cordova\lib\build.js` find this:

`var distributionUrl = 'distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip'`;

And replace it with your own file's location:

`var distributionUrl = 'distributionUrl=../gradle-2.2.1-all.zip';`

Still working on build and will keep on posting the solution. A thread about other issues  is created in  ionic forum and it is [here](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/could-not-resolve-all-dependencies-for-configuration/27573).

Comment: No, HTTP status 403 shouldn't be considered as a network issue; it is a permission issue in client, or a configuration error in server.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution for not Gradle 403 Http response**

find distributionUrl variable in:

`myapp\platforms\android\cordova\lib\builders\GradleBuilder.js`

change `http` value to `https` in this line:

```
var distributionUrl = process.env['CORDOVA_ANDROID_GRADLE_DISTRIBUTION_URL'] || 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip';
```