# Cordova error when trying to build android

Tags: cordova, build, command-line-interface

i followed this step:

1. npm install -g cordova
2. cordova create hello com.lorenzo.hello hello
3. cd hello
4. cordova platform add android
5. cordova build

it give me this error:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\gcappella\hello>cordova build
Running command: cmd "/s /c ""C:\Documents and Settings\gcappella\hello\platform
s\android\cordova\build.bat"""
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Android
JAVA_HOME=C:\Programmi\Java\jdk1.8.0_60
Running: C:\Documents and Settings\gcappella\hello\platforms\android\gradlew cdv
BuildDebug -b C:\Documents and Settings\gcappella\hello\platforms\android\build.
gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true
Downloading http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Serv
er returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://services.gradle.org/distribu
tions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip
        at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAcc
essManager.java:78)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:47)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL:
 http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLCo
nnection.java:1839)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLCon
nection.java:1440)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal(Download.java:59)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Download.java:45)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:60)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:47)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAcc
essManager.java:65)
        ... 3 more
Built the following apk(s):
```

Comment: This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31167159/ionic-build-android-failed-with-403-http-respose-from-gradle-java-home-not-vali

Comment: now the error is gradle that is reporting 403 with maven...i'm trying to set my proxy...