# Cannot build Android ionic project - Unrecognized SSL message

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, ionic-framework

I have created a new ionic project following the instructions on ionic's site.

I followed these steps

`ionic start myApp tabs`

`cd myApp`

`ionic platform add android`

When running `ionic serve` - the project runs fine on my computer.

When I try to run `ionic build android` so that I can deploy to my phone I get the following error:

- What went wrong:

A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

```
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0.
Required by:
     :android:unspecified
Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0.
Could not get resource 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.1.0/gradle-2.1.0.pom'.
Could not GET 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.1.0/gradle-2.1.0.pom'.
Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0.
Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.1.0/gradle-2.1.0.pom'.
Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.1.0/gradle-2.1.0.pom'.
Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
```

The first resource I could not GET https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.1.0/gradle-2.1.0.pom I see an xml page no 404 error.

The second link https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.1.0/gradle-2.1.0.pom downloads the .pom file with no issues.

Not sure what to make of the Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?

```
ionic version: 2.0.0

gradle version: 2.13

cordova version: 6.3.1
```

Answer (score 2):

Although I was on my home network and not on my company's vpn, my company computer uses Cisco Web Security which was blocking the two sites above.

Answer (score 1):

Try to turn off your firewall; helps if it is a network issue  and any the URLs are blocked somehow.

Furthermore, I figured that Andriod studio itself have graddle issue. If you are using SDK installed via Andriod studio then first try resolving it. Here are some links that might help you.

[Android Studio graddle 2.1.3 issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39000831/android-studio-graddle-2-1-3-issue)

and

[Ionic build android failed with 403 Http respose from Gradle, JAVA_HOME not valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31167159/ionic-build-android-failed-with-403-http-respose-from-gradle-java-home-not-vali/31187506#31187506)

And, you seem to have installed `ionic 2.0` which uses `angular 2.0` . This issue appears if you meant to use `ionic 1.0` but have ionic CLI for 2.0.

Try the following

```
npm install -g ionic @1.x
ionic start myApp tabs
cd myApp    
ionic platform add android
ionic build android.
```

Good luck. Let me know if this doesn't work for you.

Comment: Yes, this will solve an issue I have not run into yet since I do plan to use Angular 1. But it did not solve my current issue. Uninstalled and reinstalled ionic version 1.7.16 and had the same error message.

Comment: Updated answer for you. Give it a try.

Comment: I temporarily turned off my firewall. My buildscript already had the repositories listed like the 1st links answer. I tried changing the distributionUrl as the 2nd link suggest but unfortunately I am still getting the same error. Will try on another computer tomorrow and update.